# How to fix Laravel Auth Mocking not working?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to mock the Auth facade so I can mock the `Auth::user()` method. I need this because I source my users from another database.

In production, this all works fine. However, when I try and write tests for this and try something like;

```
$user = User::factory()->create();
Auth::shouldReceive('user')->andReturn($user);

$response = $this->postJson(route('api.login'), [
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'test-password'
])->assertOk();
```

I get a very bizarre error that to be honest I'm not even sure what it means.

```
Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_2_Illuminate_Auth_AuthManager::userResolver(), but no expectations were specified in Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(34) : eval()'d code:927
```

I have found very little about this error online and can't really figure out what it even means. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Why not just use [`actingAs`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication) in your request instead of mocking the facade yourself?

Comment: @BrianThompson I would usually. But this specific endpoint is testing the actual user/pass login auth itself. My controller for this test calls `Auth::attempt([])` which is what I'm trying to mock.

Comment: I see, that much makes sense. But I still wonder if this is the best way to go about the test. If the user has already been added to the DB by your factory, `Auth::attempt` will load that user record without needing to be mocked. Then your assertion can be on the JSON response or something like that.

Comment: @BrianThompson you are right, the way to test this is just use a factory with correct data, and then let Auth use that DB (where the user is) just to authenticate the user... if you are using 2 different databases, no worries, you have to have 2 local databases, one for testing and the second one is the "remote testing database" so you can fake connecting to an external DB and everything will still work... Author, add more info as your solution is not mocking Auth, there is a better solution, but we need more info about it please.

Answer (score 0):

In mockery you have partial mocks, that only mocks the specified methods and let everything else slip through. I have found [issues](https://github.com/mockery/mockery/issues/242) that indicate this also exists in `Laravel` for facades, a bit old so not certain but it is worth a try.

```
Auth::shouldReceive('user')->andReturn($user);
Auth::makePartial();
```

Comment: I'm on L8, this still led to an error in running the test `"call_user_func(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, no array or string given"` from the file `".../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php"`